# d3.select().append().attr().style() returns TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, d3.js

Inside an angular component's ngOnInit, have following code:

```
        var root = d3.select('#chart')
            .append('svg')
            .attr({
                'width': width,
                'height': height,
            })
            .style('border', '1px solid black');
```

Linked template file has simply:
`<div id="chart"></div>`

Yet once loaded on page get
`angular.js?17fa:15635 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`, pointing to the `.style` line.

Already verified d3 is imported correctly, the template shows elements otherwise, and can otherwise use d3 selector (in other examples).

Comment: Thought I was following this pretty exactly: 
http://code.hazzens.com/d3tut/lesson_2.html

Comment: Also I'm using v7 of d3

Comment: Do `.attr('width', width).attr('height', height)` instead of `.attr({'width': width, 'height': height})`